# Mysql Results and array manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am stuck working on a problem, and would appreciate some guidance. I am working with an old system that was coded awfully, and didnt do any validating, or sanitzing of user input, so the database I'm working with is a bit missy.

I have issues with one column called "tags", used for tags for articles. But *each row* appears like this, and varies between them:

**tag tag1 tag2 tag3**

OR

**tag1, tag2, tag**

But I need to combine them and put them into an array that lists them by how many times each one occurs, like this:

- **tag(2)**
- **tag1(2)**
- **tag2(2)**
- **tag3(1)**

Because I'm not the most astute with php, Im not sure if I am going about the problem correctly?

Im new to manipulating arrays on this scale which is why I am stuck at this point. You can view the example below of what I am doing below:

```
  $sql = "SELECT tags, approved FROM articles WHERE approved = '1' ";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { 
  $arr = $rows['tags'];
  $arr = str_replace(", ", " ", $arr); // attempting to clean up the data, so that each word appends with a space.
  $arr = str_replace(" ", " ", $arr);

  // Don't know what to do next, or if this is even the right way to do it.

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Lea

Comment: I think I get stuck because the script outputs an array for each row, and Im not sure how to go about manipulating, and all of my attempts of the past hour have failed

Comment: You can convert a string into an array with the `explode` function.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - True, but that doesn't deal with the way each row of data is formatted. It places it into an array like:

array() {
  [0] => tag, tag1, tag3, tag4
  [1] => tag, tag2, tag6, tag7
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful.  Modified your code to have a `$tagArr` for each query.  If you need an overall array of tags it would be a bit different, but could easily be coded using the following.

```
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { 
  $arr = $rows['tags'];
  $arr = str_replace(", ", " ", $arr); // attempting to clean up the data, so that each word appends with a space.

  // Don't know what to do next, or if this is even the right way to do it.

  $tagArr = array();
  $current_tags = explode(" ", $arr);
  foreach($current_tags as $tag) {
    if(!array_key_exists($tag, $tagArr)) {
      $tagArr[$tag] = 1;
    } else {
      $tagArr[$tag] = $tagArr[$tag]++;
    }
  }

  // now $tagArr has the tag name as it's key, and the number of occurrences as it's value
  foreach($tagArr as $tag => $occurrences) {
    echo $tag . '(' . $occurrences . ')<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for the *str_replace space with space* line.

Comment: @Lea Updated the code.  I just traversed through the new `$tagArr` array and echoed the information.  Also removed the unneeded `str_replace`.

Comment: Aaron W. - I see now. Thanks for your help:)