# Mysql array data manipulation

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `articles` table with a `tags` column. Each row in the column contains a string that looks like:

`tag1, tag3, tag5, tag0 // separated via a comma`

OR

`tag1 tag6 tag5 tag8 // separated via a space`

Note that the number appended to "tag" signifies a different word. I need to compare **each** row for duplicates and return the amount of times a word was duplicated, and then put it into a loop like:

- tag0 (1 times)
- tag1 (2 times)
- tag3 (1 times)
- tag6 (1 times)
- tag8 (1 times)

If you can help me, you will have my genuine thanks, after 6 hours of failed attempts. I did ask this same question earlier, but accepted the answer too soon. [Mysql Results and array manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554309/mysql-results-and-array-manipulation)

Comment: Take each of the tag fields, explode them join as 1 big list, then count by tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why a denormalized database design fails you - you lose any ability to easily do relational queries. Given that SQL databases have horrible string manipulation facilities compared to 'external' programming languages, you'll want to suck out all those tag strings into PHP and do the deconstruction/counting there.

Had your database been properly normalized, with a seperate sub-table to link tags<->articles, the query would've been a trivial

```
SELECT tag.name, count(articles_tags.article_id) AS cnt
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN article_tags ON tags.id = articles_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY tag.id
ORDER BY tag.name
```

Now you're stuck with

```
SELECT id, tags from ARTICLES
```

and

```
$tag_count = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $tags = preg_split('/[ ,]/', $row['tags']);
   foreach($tags as $tag) {
       $tag_count[$tag]++;
   }
}
sort($tag_count);
```

Comment: Of course, I completely agree. But I didnt create the system, and I am just working with whats there. Had I created it, then I would do exactly as you have described.

Comment: If you were near me I would worship at your feet. Its 7am, I can now goto sleep. THANK YOU SO MUCH